# when I compile with Scite, command prompt won't show up, why?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, command-prompt, scite

when I compile with Scite, command prompt won't show up, why?
I am programming a c program, and it wouldn't pop up once I complied
is it because its not connected? or do I have to connect it, if so how?

Comment: On what system are you running? On Linux, the compiler is usually `gcc` (with a command only interface), and any fancy tool -even `scite` or other *scintilla* based editor- would just start `gcc` internally. So if you are on Linux, try to compile with a command on the terminal (starting with `gcc -Wall`)

Comment: I am running on windows

Comment: It is probably the same on Windows. Your `scite` tool is ultimately starting a command for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an old version (10 year) so the description may not match yours: on my 'Parameter Dialog' there is a setting called 'Sub-system'.
 When sub-system is set to 'Command-line-interface', all child processes are created with pipe to trap child output to the 'Output pane'. No 'Cmd window' in this case.
 When sub-system is set to anything else : 'GUI', 'Shell' ... the child process is running free, not communicating with SciTE: either Normal window or Cmd window show- up in this case.
Check your 'Parameter Dialog' or 'cpp.config' file to make sure the 'Go command' is not called under 'Command-line-interface' sub-system.